# Is limestone robbed out from pyramids ever seen in local use?

Tags: pyramids

So, in most Roman archaeological sites most of the stone work is “robbed out” but it can be found re-used in churches and other buildings.
But I often hear that the limestone covering the pyramids was stolen or robbed. My question is: is this ever seen being re-used locally?

Comment: To avoid duplication of effort, what research have you already done about the limestone facings?

Answer (score 5):

**Alabaster Mosque**

The answer is likely yes, there is at least one example, as it has been claimed that the [Alabaster Mosque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosque_of_Muhammad_Ali#History) in the Citadel of Cairo is built using limestone from the Great Pyramid.

[The Vintage News](https://www.thevintagenews.com/2016/09/06/the-great-pyramid-of-giza-was-once-covered-in-highly-polished-white-limestone-before-it-was-removed-to-build-mosques-and-fortresses/?chrome=1)

> the Great Pyramid was surfaced by white “casing stones.” These casing stones were intricately cut, beautifully polished blocks of white limestone.

> In addition, plenty more casing stones were removed from the Great Pyramid by Muhammad Ali Pasha during the early 19th century and reused as material for his Alabaster Mosque, also in Cairo.

Comment: Thanks John much appreciated